# How to onclick, innerHTML to a new page

Tags: javascript, api, onclick

here is my script but for now it innerHTML to the same page. I wrap my movie card in a tag, to redirect to the second page, but i'm unable to figure out how make this excute the fuunction displayMovieInfo() in the target page. i've been trying to figure it out and make researches for 3 days now, with no success. i would appreciate your help ( im learning JS )

```
getMovies(API_URL)

async function getMovies(url) {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();

    console.log(data);

    displayMovies(data.results);
}

function displayMovies(movies) {
    moviesWrapper.innerHTML = '';
    // movies.forEach((movie) => {
    movies.slice(-4).forEach((movie) => {
        const { title, poster_path, vote_average, overview } = movie;
        const movieElement = document.createElement('div');
        movieElement.classList.add('movie-card');

        movieElement.innerHTML = `
        <a href="film.html"><img src="${IMAGE_PATH + poster_path}" alt="${title}"/>
        <div class='movie-content'>
        
        <div class='desc'>
        <h2>${title}</h2>
        ${vote_average}
        </div>
        </div>
        </a>
        `
        moviesWrapper.appendChild(movieElement);


        movieElement.onclick = function displayMovieInfo() {


            const movieInfo = document.getElementById('about');

            // movieInfoContainer.classList.add('about');
            movieInfo.innerHTML = `
            <h2 class="about-title">${title}</h2>
            <hr>
                <div class='about-content'>
                <img class="about-img" src="${IMAGE_PATH + poster_path}" alt="${title}"/>
                <div class='description'>
                <p>${overview}<p>
                </div>
                </div>
                `
                // movieInfo.appendChild(movieSpec);

            movieInfo.scrollIntoView(true);
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: Do you want to display your movieElement in another html file?

Comment: yes exactly ! 

the API fetch is excuted in index.html and i want when the user click on a movie card , load the second page (film.html) and display the movie info details on the targeted div

Comment: In that case you will have to send some parameters to the href in your <a> tag, then run a script in the other html to obtain those values using window.location.search to finally create the HTML element and append it.